# Unity 2019.4.0.0f1 Under Services Tab, the "Select organization" is empty despite being logged in and having organizations setup online

Tags: unity-game-engine, service, in-app-purchase, cloud, organization

Under the services tab, the "select organization" dropdown is empty.  I also added a new organization and project from the web site but this also doesn't show up even if I click the "I already have a Unity Project ID" link.  I've logged off and back in on the Unity GUI client to no avail.

I have a student license but I can't find any documentation that talk about which restrictions are applied and if services are one of them.  Is this a restriction mentioned somewhere?  Do I need to do something different to make this work?

If this is due to being having a student license, is my only option to buy a separate license?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this as a bug to Unity and they confirmed that it is an issue they are aware of.

The issue can be tracked here: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/product/unity/issues/guid/1260030

If you have this same issue, please click on the link above and vote on it!